# A way to make a mobile web page secure?

Tags: php, html, mobile, security

Is there a way to make a mobile web page secure? (Encrypting or some secure way of make information secure)

I have heard that mobile web development environment is much different from formal web development.

I would like to make a mobile web page secure with mobile-web-only-tags (HTML), if possible.

Or any recommendations with server-side way (PHP) to make a page secure?

Comment: Define "secure". What does your web page do?

Comment: Security measures which apply to desktop web development also apply to mobile.

Comment: What kind of "mobile" are you targeting? WAP? iMode? iOS/Android/Opera mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what your site is written in, some extra care may need to be taken. If your site is written completely in Javascript for example, then you must take extra care to prevent any XSS injection. OWASP is the number one source for this (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Avoid document.write to dynamically create HTML, and instead use a templating framework like Mustache.js

If you submit any forms to your server, do client side validation but do not let this be your last line of defense. Like any website, server side validation is your primary defense against SQLi etc, but use the depth of defense tactics. Use SSL when submitting private information.

If you take any user input and then display it again, for example in a search form, then ensure you remove any HTML from that input.

Mobile web development is not very different from desktop dev, the same security principles are important and always apply. Also, your point about making a website secure using HTML tags is misguided. HTML does not provide security, it's merely a markup language.